# Calculate Mean of Comma-Separated String of Numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a column in my dataframe that is made up of strings of numbers, separated by commas. I would like to convert the string to a list of numbers, and then get the mean. My dataframe, `df`:

```
a3
1,5,2
103.1
34,6
```

First, I converted the string to a list:

```
> df$a3_list <- strsplit(as.character(df$a3), split = ',')
```

New `df`:

```
a3    a3_list
1,5,2 c("1", "5", "2")
103.1 103.1
34,6  c("34", "6")
```

At this point, however, I'm not sure how to get a new column containing the mean of each cell in `df$a3_list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stringi`, it's fast

```
library(stringi)
mat <- stri_split_fixed(df$a3, ',', simplify=T)
mat <- `dim<-`(as.numeric(mat), dim(mat))  # convert to numeric and save dims
rowMeans(mat, na.rm=T)
# [1]   2.666667 103.100000  20.000000
```

or with Base R

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$a3), ",", fixed=T), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
```

Comment: I tried ``df3$a3_mean <- mean(as.numeric(stri_split_fixed(df3$a3, ',', simplify=T)), na.rm=T)``, but it gave me the same mean for every row. I would like the individual means for each row

Comment: @Adam_G the code you show in this comment is not functionally the same as the code nongkrong posted.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I want to add a new column. nongkrong's code doesn't do that.

Comment: just do `df$newCol <- ` either of the solutions

Comment: @nongkrong - I tried that with the second solution, but get "Error in strsplit(df3$a3, ",", fixed = T) : non-character argument
"

Comment: @Adam_G Looks like you have a `factor `column.  So wrap it with `as.character` ie. `strsplit(as.character(df3$a3),...`

Answer (score 3):

Another `base R` option

```
 rowMeans(read.table(text=df$a3, sep=",", fill=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE)
 #[1]   2.666667 103.100000  20.000000
```

NOTE: Assuming that the 'a3' is `character` class.  Otherwise, wrap with `as.character(df$a3)`

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(a3 = c("1,5,2", "103.1", "34,6")), .Names = "a3", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I get "Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  invalid 'text' argument"

Comment: @Adam_G The `data I used is updated in the post.  I didn't get any error